# What legal action can you take if someone calls you a sex offender with no proof?

Tags: defamation, sexual-assault

Just went through a nasty custody battle and won sole custody and he has taken it upon himself to call my fiance a sexual abusive person to our 2 yr old child. He has blasted it on social media and even though he is blocked he keeps finding ways to try and accuse him. Is there anything we can do, we are so tired of dealing with this...

Answer (score 7):

This is defamation, a civil matter, where you may sue the person who makes these statements. If you sue them, the question is whether accusing a person of sexually abusing a 2 year old would lower the person in the eyes of others, and the answer is "Yes, you don't even have to prove that there was actual harm" (this is know as *per se* defamation): it is both accusation of a crime and accusation of reprehensible moral conduct. Making the statement in public is all it takes – "public" means "someone other than the object of the accusation". The only defense is proving that the statement is true. Your attorney can advise you how much money you might awarded in a successful suit, also any downside to suing the ex. If you are playing defamation whack-a-mole, this probably involves getting an injunction against doing this again.